# Derivative of a BM's time-integral (non-closed form)

Tags: integration, derivatives, self-learning, brownian-motion

I am struggeling to make sence of the following derivative. Let $Y_t$ be a standard BM and define

$$D_t =  \left(\int_0^t Y_s^\gamma \exp(\alpha s)~ds \right)^{1/\gamma}$$

I claim that $D_t$ does not attain a closed-form solution. Yet the **question** is, if one can solve the derivative

$$\frac{\partial D_t}{\partial Y_t} =~?$$

I tried approximating the integral by Riemann sums, but then the result would be that the derivative is zero (as the derivative of the sum contains a $\Delta t$-term which goes to zero). Is this the correct result?